# Cometd Java Client won't publish to Cometd server

Tags: java, android, jetty, cometd

I followed the examples that I could find for making a Cometd java client application.  I am trying to make it so when the user presses a button on the screen, cometd publishes a message to the server.  Right now the publish gets called but the server never receives message to its listener.  I have this server listener working with javascript but not java code.

Client side setup is as follows:

```
        // Prepare the transport
        Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        ClientTransport transport = LongPollingTransport.create(options, httpClient);

        _client = new BayeuxClient("http://10.100.97.168:8888/slideshow/slideshow/", transport);
        _client.getChannel(Channel.META_HANDSHAKE).addListener(new InitializerListener());
        _client.getChannel(Channel.META_CONNECT).addListener(new ConnectionListener());
```

My handshake and connection listeners:

```
private class InitializerListener implements ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener
    {
        public void onMessage(ClientSessionChannel channel, Message message)
        {
            if (message.isSuccessful())
            {
                _handshaked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                _handshaked = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private class ConnectionListener implements ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener
    {
        private boolean wasConnected;
        private boolean connected;

        public void onMessage(ClientSessionChannel channel, Message message)
        {
            if (_client.isDisconnected())
            {
                connected = false;
                connectionClosed();
                return;
            }

            wasConnected = connected;
            connected = message.isSuccessful();
            if (!wasConnected && connected)
            {
                connectionEstablished();
            }
            else if (wasConnected && !connected)
            {
                connectionBroken();
            }
        }
    }
```

Button press that tries to publish:

```
_btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(_connection_established == true)
                {
                    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    _clientSessionChannel.publish(data);
                }
            }
         });
```

Just in case here is my server Listener too:

```
@Listener("/service/slide/play")
    public void processServiceSlidePlay(ServerSession client, ServerMessage message)
    {
        synchronized(imagelock)
        {
            if(slideShowRunning == false && imageIDList != null && imageIDList.size() > 0)
            {
                slideShowRunning = true;
                if(imageIDList != null && imageIDList.size() > 0)
                {           
                    deliverChangeMessage(client, message);  
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So I can establish a connection and my publish gets called, but the server never picks it up.  Also I noticed if I do the same exact publish but in my handshake or connect callback, the server will pick it up.  Seems like I just can't do a publish outside of the callbacks.

Thanks in Advance for the Help.

Comment: Sorry but your question is incomplete. It does not show where `_connection_established` is set, nor what is `_clientSessionChannel` initialize to. It could be that the former is never set to true, or the latter is initialized with the wrong channel name, etc. If your publishes work from other places, it means that CometD itself works fine, and the problem is in your code.

Comment: Your complaints are invalid to answering the question, I stated that _clientSessionChannel.publish(data); gets called so you don't have to worry about _connection_established and that _clientSessionChannel works at certain times so that is valid too.  It turned out that I was trying to run network code on the Main UI thread and that is not allowed in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I was running the network, cometD code, on Androids Main UI Thread and that is not allowed.  Once I moved all the cometd code over to an AsyncTask it all started working all the time.

Comment: Hey Michael, 
are you using eclipse for your development. I am not able to configure my android project to use the cometd java client. I keep getting the NoClassDefFound exception, for indirect dependencies.